# AJAX TTFB 1.5 seconds slower than GET request

Tags: ajax, performance, get, pagespeed

API script outputs 2kb of data:

TTFB from `ajax` call is 1.65s on average

TTFB from `GET` request is 100ms

Is there a discussion to be had around AJAX vs GET requests when considering TTFB? I cannot find anything online to suggest what may cause this discrepancy.

Comment: The page's Get probably is eliminated because page can be cached, where as you trigger ajax calls directly like in update panel.. Usually Ajax get/post request are quicker because no need to reload whole page.. Not sure I fully understood the question though..

Comment: If I load the URL in the browser my TTFB is 100ms. If I load the URL through AJAX the TTFB is 1650ms. I'm at a loss as to how that's possible.

Comment: When you load through AJAX are you not using a browser, which program then you use..

Comment: I don't follow the question, sorry. I'm loading the resource through $.ajax and it takes 1650ms. When I load the resource through a GET request i.e. browser load, it's 100ms. What could cause an AJAX request to take 16 times longer?

Comment: Try remove browser cache, also if you could provide your ajax code it would help to see if anything wrong with it..

Comment: @numbtongue not sure you understand what AJAX is. OP I'm noticing this issue too, might be something to do with connection congestion